# After reboot: NullReferenceException at System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

(Almost) every morning, after booting my laptop, starting IIS, and browsing to a specific asp.net mvc web application on my PC, I get this exception:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) +1781
   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb) +130
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +481
```

After iisreset, this is solved. It only happens at my own laptop, not on a stage or live server where the same asp.net mvc application is running

I already checked:

- I didn't add any custom eventhandlers in my global.asax
- I have no custom HTTPModules of my own. I do use ImageResizer, but no eventhandlers are defined for that module (that I'm aware of and can be seen in the code).
- I did try to move the code from Application_BeginRequest to the global.Asax constructor but ran into another issue because in the constructor I don't have any HttpContext.Current yet.
- (I know what a NullReferenceException means, so no need to explain that. In this case the exception isn't thrown by my own code.)

I'm using an app pool in Integrated mode on .net CLR version 4.0.30319
Target framework is .Net 4.5.2

my global.asax looks like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication {

        protected void Application_Start() {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeModelBinder());
            ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new NullableDateTimeModelBinder());

            ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "ValidationMessages";
            DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "ValidationMessages";
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(LanguageHelpers.GetUserCultureName());
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        }

        public void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (!Request.IsLocal) {

....

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Owen, thanks for the comment, but I already know what a nullref is. In this case the exception didn't occur in my code, but in MS's own code.

Answer (score 0):

After taking look at error on internet, i think you have two option.

1. Remove all HTTP Module if any added in your system.
2. Remove IIS from Control panel --> Programs & Feature --> Turn off/on Window Feature
   Remove Internet Information Services and reboot and install again.

See if this works or not.

Also, do you getting this error for any other project or maybe create new one and check this out? If yes then probably reintalling IIS will fix this.

[Server error '/' Application. - HttpException](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cb6a04e1-19d6-4a75-be25-aca16b89f166/server-error-application-httpexception-0x80004005?forum=winformssetup)

Comment: I don't have any http modules. Reinstalling IIS might work of course, but I'd prefer a less invase way. You can call me ignorant, but I'd still like to know what actually goes wrong here.

Comment: You can you check IIS logs and see stack trace or whats going under the hood?